# Ошибка при импорте существующего файла - "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, импорт

Я создаю простую текстовую игру.
Создал player.py в папке Players, и classes.yaml в папке yaml.
Мои папки:

```
Game
|__ yaml
    |__ Players
```

В player.py я импортирую classes:

```
import yaml

with open("yaml/classes.yaml") as classes:
    info = yaml.safe_load(classes.read())
```

И мне выдает ошибку:

```
File "<string>", line 3, in module
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'yaml/classes.yaml'
```

Пробывал переименовывать, добавлять в другие папки - все тщетно.
Хотелось бы оставить каждый файл на своем месте, если это возможно.
Что пошло не так?

Comment: А почему не добавляете 'r' в open?

Comment: Всё просто: в **рабочей** директории нет пути `yaml/classes.yaml`.

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов, по умолчанию `'r'` и так используется, поэтому не нужно при открытии в режиме текстового чтения указывать

Comment: У вас в `yaml/` папка `Players/`? Или напутали с форматированием списков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина проблемы -- в рабочей директории.

При запуске `player.py` рабочей будет папка с `player.py`, а при указании относительного пути, оно будет строиться **относительно** рабочей директории, т.е. файл будет искаться по пути: `Players/yaml/classes.yaml`.

Один из вариантов это сделать путь в `player.py` с указанием родительской папки:

```
import yaml

with open("../yaml/classes.yaml") as classes:
    info = yaml.safe_load(classes.read())
```

Но у него есть минус. Допустим вы решите запустить `main.py` из папки `Game/`, а в этом скрипте сделать импорт `players.player.py`, в `player.py` будет загрузка с `"../yaml/classes.yaml"`, но рабочая папка теперь другая, а именно -- `Game/`, поэтому `/yaml/classes.yaml` не будет найден, т.к. поиск будет в папке выше `Game/`.

Для решения этого нужно или указывать абсолютные пути (но это не переносимо между компьютерами) или использовать относительные пути, но в одном месте содержать путь к папке проекта и относительно этого пути строить другие.

---

#### Решаем проблему доступа к файлам проекта

Сделал новый проект и построил в нем такую структуру:

```
├── players/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── player.py
│
├── yaml/
│   ├── classes.yaml
│
├── config.py
├── main.py
```

Где:

- `players/__init__.py`: пустой, он нужно только для того, чтобы папка `player/` считалась пакетом
- `players/player.py`:

  ```py
  import config
  import yaml

  with open(config.DIR_YAML_CLASSES) as classes:
      info = yaml.safe_load(classes.read())

  print(info)
  ```
- `config.py`, тут формируется общий путь относительно папки проекта:

  ```
  import inspect
  import os
  import sys
  from pathlib import Path


  # SOURCE: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/927af3d3f05a0129338b21d074ca241c8a055118/get_current_script_dir.py
  def get_current_script_dir(follow_symlinks=True, normcase=False) -> str:
      # py2exe, PyInstaller, cx_Freeze
      if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
          path = os.path.abspath(sys.executable)
      else:
          # Analog inspect.getabsfile without os.path.normcase
          path = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename
          path = os.path.abspath(path)

      if follow_symlinks:
          path = os.path.realpath(path)

      if normcase:
          path = os.path.normcase(path)

      return os.path.dirname(path)


  DIR = Path(get_current_script_dir())
  DIR_YAML = DIR / 'yaml'
  DIR_YAML_CLASSES = DIR_YAML / "classes.yaml"
  ```
- `yaml/classes.yaml`:

  ```yaml
  classes: [Mage, Knight]
  ```
- `main.py`, сделаем импорт `player.py`:

  ```
  import players.player
  ```

ℹ️ При запуске `main.py` и `player.py` будет выведено `{'classes': ['Mage', 'Knight']}`, что говорит о том, что файл был успешно найден

ℹ️ Может случиться ситуация импорта скрипта, который находится, например, папкой выше. Для этого можно сделать добавление пути в его папку в `sys.path` (при импорте в указанным в нем папках и будет поиск), пример:

```
import sys
import os.path

# Добавление папки выше рабочей
sys.path.append('..')
# или указывая абсолютный, чтобы путь был более понятным при выводе всех путей
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..'))

# Вывести все пути, где поиск при импорте
print(*sys.path, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Перед вашем кодом перейдите в каталог приложения

```
import sys, os

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # frozen
        appdir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # plain
        appdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    os.chdir(os.path.abspath(appdir))
```