# Корневая область видимости (пути)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть вот такая структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким способом можно указать НЕ абсолютный путь до файла?

Нужно чтобы это работало:

```
stats_path = 'logs\\stats.txt'
```

p.s. Нашёл способ перехода по структуре проекта через точки: `.\\` / `..\\`, но правильный ли это подход?

```
stats_path = '..\\..\\logs\\stats.txt'
```

Comment: Точки правильно, но перед ними нужно поставить абсолютный путь. Если запустить прогу с ярлыка, то точки окажутся около ярлыка, а не там где нужно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1174650/16574

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашёл такое:

```
from pathlib import Path


def root_path() -> Path:
    """Returns project root folder."""
    return Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent  # Тут выход в корень проекта
```

Создал "хелпер" обращаясь к нему, получаю корневой путь.

Как это выглядит на практике:

```
import os

from utils.misc.root_path import root_path

STATS_PATH = os.path.join(root_path(), 'logs\\stats.txt')
print(STATS_PATH)  # D:\Projects\idle bot\logs\stats.txt
```

Теперь перемещение файлов/компонентов/модулей (и их вызов) всегда правильно определяют путь и не нужно рефакторить их

Comment: Вместо функции лучше заведите переменную в модуле, типа: `DIR = Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent` и используйте оператор `/` для составления пути в объекте `Path`, пример: `STATS_PATH = DIR / 'logs/stats.txt'` (просто `pathlib` замена `os.path`, поэтому нет смысла их смешивать)

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо за отклик, но если я перенесу модуль в другую папку\путь, то мне же нужно опять будет в ручную изменять `DIR = Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent`, что не очень практично (я так думаю)

Comment: А функцию менять не нужно? О_о Я в корне проекта создаю файл `config.py`, в нем такую переменную и этот модуль использую везде, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/master/config.py#L11

Comment: @gil9red, только если я перенесу "хелпер" в другое расположение (путь)

Comment: У вас функция все-равно привязана к модулю, где она объявлена из-за `__file__`, и в любом файле скрипта выдаст один результат, поэтому, думаю, что выполнять этот код каждый раз нет смысла -- пусть будет в переменной

Comment: @gil9red, я понял о чем вы говорите и да это вроде как практичнее вызывать из конфига (переменной), еще раз спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад был помочь :)